# How to print data frame column names containing parentheses in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to print the following in R:

```
f(x)
   1
   2
   3
```

I tried:

```
print(data.frame("f(x)" = 1:3), row.names = F)
```

However, the parentheses get converted to periods:

```
f.x.
   1
   2
   3
```

How can I print parentheses in column names? Of course, I could just write `print("f(x)\n   1\n   2...")`, but I need this to be from a data frame.

Comment: `print(data.frame("f(x)" = 1:3, check.names = FALSE), row.names = F)`

Comment: The printing is fine. It's actually when you create the `data.frame` that the names are changed. This is because R tries to avoid column names that cannot be used as simple variable names. As already pointed out, you can turn that checking off with `check.names=FALSE` but using such column names can make things a lot messier depending on what you want to do with the data.

Comment: `check.names=F` is exactly what I was looking for, thank you! Add as an answer and I will credit it as such.